# Wildcard Query for SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I tried using this example as search parameter "Share*" but the result return nothing.

Interestingly,if i try searching for the word "share" i do get the result containing the SharePoint word. That great but it only works with this particular example. If i try to search for "docume",i don't get the result "document" returned. My purpose for wild card is to search content of files only

```
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);

            keywordQuery.QueryText = SearchParameter;

            keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;



            keywordQuery.EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty = true;
            //keywordQuery.SummaryLength = 500;


            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryText is always wild card if you are not specifying any column , it just check for 'Share' keyword in your content and if found will return result, not sure why you need wild card. Wildcard(*) only make sense when you are search values for a particular property.

You can add a * for suffix wildcard matching like below. last one is for phrase search so enclosed with quotes.

MyProperty:words or MyProperty:word* or MyProperty:"these words".

Comment: "QueryText is always wild card"--if i try searching for the word  "share" i do get the result containing the SharePoint word. That great but it only works with this particular example. If i try to search for "docume",i don't get the result document returned. My purpose for wild card is to search content of files only.

Comment: @KeshavTaurah...are you sure you are not missing something...as i said by default it is wild card only....please check that particular document which is not returning is be in crawled or not...

Comment: Vaghasia i actually figured it out,sometime the wildcard works without using * but if i used the * it works all the time

Comment: okay... please upvote and mark it as answer it was helpful..